# Taking input from file into list in python

Tags: python, file-io

Is there some way for taking input from a file other than using for loop ?
I am using,

```
data = fileinput.input()
c = [int(i) for i in data]
c.sort()
```

But for very large amount of data, it takes too long to process.
input is of the format,

```
58457907
37850775
19743393
70718573
....
```

Comment: you are essentially processing the file 3 times - do you really need to sort it at the end? - try just opening the file and reading thru it, the first line reads the entire file then you process each line, and then you sort it - no wonder it takes a long time

Comment: Almost any construct has an implicit loop. Why are you avoiding an explicit loop?

Comment: its a 888 kb text file with around 100002 lines.
and sorting is required for further processing...

Comment: fileinput adds some overhead. If you are sensitive to time, you may consider opening the files yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If I create a 'large' file:

```
from random import randint 

with open('/tmp/nums.txt', 'w') as fout:
    a,b=100002/10000, 100002*10000
    for i in range(100002):
        fout.write('{}\n'.format(randint(a,b)))
```

I can read it, convert it to integers, and sort in place the data thus:

```
with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin:    
    nums=[int(e) for e in fin]
    nums.sort()
```

The total time for this operation is 50 ms on my computer. Is 50 ms a long time?

---

With a more formal timing:

```
def f1():
    with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin:    
        nums=[int(e) for e in fin]
        nums.sort()
    return nums

def f2():
    with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin:  
        return sorted(map(int, fin))

def f3():
    with open('/tmp/nums.txt') as fin:  
        nums=list(map(int, fin))
        nums.sort()    
    return nums    

if __name__ =='__main__':
    import timeit     
    import sys
    if sys.version_info.major==2:
        from itertools import imap as map

    result=[]    
    for f in (f1, f2, f3):
        fn=f.__name__
        fs="f()"
        ft=timeit.timeit(fs, setup="from __main__ import f", number=3)
        r=eval(fs)
        result.append((ft, fn, str(r[0:5])+'...'+str(r[-6:-1]) ))         

    result.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])    

    for i, t in enumerate(result):
        ft, fn, r = t
        if i==0:
            fr='{}: {:.4f} secs is fastest\n\tf(x)={}\n========'.format(fn, ft, r)   
        else:
            t1=result[0][0]
            dp=(ft-t1)/t1
            fr='{}: {:.4f} secs - {} is {:.2%} faster\n\tf(x)={}'.format(fn, ft, result[0][1], dp, r)

        print(fr)
```

You can see that the differences between these are not *huge* (except for PyPy where f3 clearly has an advantage):

Python 2.7.8:

```
f3: 0.2630 secs is fastest
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
========
f2: 0.2641 secs - f3 is 0.41% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
f1: 0.2779 secs - f3 is 5.67% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
```

Python 3.4.1:

```
f2: 0.1873 secs is fastest
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
========
f3: 0.1881 secs - f2 is 0.41% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
f1: 0.2071 secs - f2 is 10.59% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
```

PyPy:

```
f3: 0.1300 secs is fastest
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
========
f2: 0.1428 secs - f3 is 9.81% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
f1: 0.2223 secs - f3 is 70.94% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
```

PyPy3:

```
f3: 0.2483 secs is fastest
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
========
f2: 0.2588 secs - f3 is 4.23% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
f1: 0.2878 secs - f3 is 15.88% faster
    f(x)=[3025, 18834, 19637, 29124, 42088]...[999964829, 999970030, 999984585, 1000005692, 1000010131]
```

Comment: using fileinput.FileInput instead of open added about 65% more time in some tests I did.

Comment: Yeah its much faster then my previous one.. thanks..
but here i am using a input file.. which will be provided explicitly using parameters..

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Is your program being provided the name of a file or the 100,002 numbers though stdin? Fileinput supports either/both.

Comment: I first wrote the code with stdin but for testing purpose i used testcase file.. which took a lot of time in execution...

Answer (score 3):

Using `readlines` and `map` using `with` to open the file seems more efficient on a test of a file with 200 lines.

```
In [3]: %%timeit
with open("in.txt",'rb') as f:
    lines = map(int,f)
    lines.sort()
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop


In [5]: %%timeit
data = fileinput.input("in.txt")
c = [int(i) for i in data]
c.sort()
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 443 µs per loop
```

Comment: @Robᵩ, literally identical timings but probably a better idea

Comment: On my PC, `lines = sorted(itertools.imap(int,f))` is marginally fastest, although `lines = sorted(int(x) for x in f)` comes close. And I hate using `map`.

Comment: just tried sorted it  was also identical will try with itertools, `180 µs` using imap